# which is better practice big one method or separated methods?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter.

i have class Orders which with some methods like `start_order(), close_order(),` etc..

and i have a permission level for each user type `'admin','salesman','manager' ..`

therefore the same method may get different implementation each time.

so, my question is: which is considered as best practice in CI :

> **1)** to make a big method in the 'orders' class that contains the
>   different logic details.  or 
>  **2)** repeat the method as needed in
>   other classes.

i know it sounds obvious that one should go for the first choice. but, when i did that i ended up with massive blocks of code. so, this is why i am asking for your experience.

Comment: You probably have a look on your design looks like design issue. Normally one method should fit to your monitor screen, and one class would be max 400 lines of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a matter of fact it is *not* obvious that one should go for the first choice ("one big method").  That should definitely be avoided.

In general, one should prefer small methods.  Each method should do exactly one thing and only one thing, have only one reason to ever change, be small and readable, be obvious from its name what it is doing, etc.

The wording you choose in your question ("different implementation each time" and "that contains the different logic details") implies that you're talking about one method which does different things based on some kind of state of the objects.

Take a look at a refactoring pattern called [Replace Conditional With Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).  This pattern is commonly used when you have a method which is primarily a big `case` check or an `if/elseif` chain which determines that state.  The idea is that you'd extract each implementation into its own class which overrides a method on a base class.  The classes would hold and know about the state and would be able to apply the correct logic accordingly, and the consuming code would just call the method on the base class type.

There is [lots of information and lots of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace%20conditional%20with%20polymorphism) on this pattern.

As [@Gordon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386766/328193), this is also called the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).

Comment: since Codeigniter allows you to have controller classes like 'admin', 'salesman' etc..
what if i put a 'start_order()' function for each controller class as needed instead of making inheritance ? since they all inherit the class CI_Controller and PHP5 does not allow multiple inheritance?

Comment: @adel: You shouldn't need multiple inheritance. If the controller classes are the ones which need to make use of the strategy pattern, you should be able to create a base controller class which inherits from `CI_Controller`, then each of your controllers would inherit from your base controller (and, subsequently, from `CI_Controller` through the inheritance hierarchy). That base controller would have the abstract `start_order()`. You'd either provide a default version in the base controller and allow override, or no version and require override. Then each controller can call `start_order()`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying you have a different class for each permission level (something like `AdminOrder`, `SalesmanOrder`, etc)? If so, it is better add a separate method in each class if the order is sufficiently different. Doing this is called method overriding, and is common in object-oriented programming. Take for instance:

```
class Order
{
    function start_order() 
    {
        // this method contains common code for all orders
    }
}

class AdminOrder extends Order
{
    function start_order()
    {
        // IF NEEDED: call start_order on Order. This is if you have common code that should be executed for ALL subclasses of Order
        parent::start_order()

        // Now implement code specific to an AdminOrder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> therefore the same method may get different implementation each time

from that follows that you want to have three methods, one for each implementation. Mixing all possible implementations into one big method will make it much harder to maintain. You will have lots of ifs and elses.

Have a look at the [Strategy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) to learn how to make this work in a good practise way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to create a base class `order` and then extend it into `admin`,`salesman` and whatever then you only need to overwrite the methods that are different

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to split big chunks of logic into separate methods You then call where needed.

Your code looks better, is readable and You will not get lost when You will need to find and repair something.

Big massive colossus methods are very bad habbit.